# python: Use a module function as a static method

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
from module import some_function
class SomeClass:
    @staticmethod
    def class_function(*args, **kwargs):
        return some_function(*args, **kwargs)
```

The static method is simply an class wrapper to `module.some_function`. Why can't I do this with simple variable assignment.

```
from module import some_function
class SomeClass:
    class_function = some_function
```

Now, `class_function` is no longer a `staticmethod`, and also the decorator can't be used. Is there a way around this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `staticmethod` the non-decorator way:

```
from module import some_function
class SomeClass:
    class_function = staticmethod(some_function)
```

Comment: Awesome. I knew it should be this way, just didn't know how wrap the decorator in a correct way. Thanks!